# Simulate ENTER key in bash script

Tags: bash, centos7

My knowledge of Linux is on the pre-school level and most of the answers I've found here - it didn't answer my problem.

I want to automate my everyday job and put the process of logging into the root user, doing some lines and logging out.
E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd /
su -
echo "my_password"
```

Here is a problem I need to confirm the password by pressing the ENTER key

doing something as root

logout

I tried:

```
echo "my_password" | su
```

But it didn't help and also tried

```
su - echo "my_password\n"
```

It didn't help either and also tried

```
su - echo -e "my_password\n"
```

It was wrong and also tried

```
su - echo "my_password" bind '\C-m'
```

It was wrong either. What is the easiest way to do that?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to make a script to automate some task?

Comment: Look into `sudo` and this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/147265/140035

Comment: Please have look at:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115758/how-to-login-as-root-from-bash-and-do-stuff

Comment: Yes, to use  one file started by doubleclick mouse button, instead of typing all lines in command line...

Comment: Putting your password in a script file is a terrible idea, especially if that password has `sudo` privileges. A much better solution is to give *quite restricted* passwordless access to one or two very specific local scripts.

Comment: It's used by everybody in the room when we work on centos7 and in local area without access to net. I could add a new user with superuser rights but the disk space is small and it would exceed the quota, the safety issue is not important in this case